# Can't create migration baseline in Prisma

Tags: postgresql, prisma

I have a Postgres table like this:

```
                                                          Table "public.topic"
     Column     |           Type           |                     Modifiers                      | Storage  | Stats target | Description 
----------------+--------------------------+----------------------------------------------------+----------+--------------+-------------
 id             | integer                  | not null default nextval('topic_id_seq'::regclass) | plain    |              | 
 parent_topicid | integer                  |                                                    | plain    |              | 
 topic          | character varying        |                                                    | extended |              | 
 public         | boolean                  | default true                                       | plain    |              | 
 creator        | character varying(12)    | collate et_EE default NULL::character varying      | extended |              | 
 created        | timestamp with time zone | not null default now()                             | plain    |              | 
 updater        | character varying(12)    | collate et_EE default NULL::character varying      | extended |              | 
 updated        | timestamp with time zone | default now()                                      | plain    |              | 
Indexes:
    "topic_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "topic_parent_topicid_idx" btree (parent_topicid)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "topics_have_parent" FOREIGN KEY (parent_topicid) REFERENCES topic(id) ON DELETE SET NULL
Referenced by:
    TABLE "book.book_topic" CONSTRAINT "book_topic_belongs_to_topic" FOREIGN KEY (topicid) REFERENCES topic(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
    TABLE "card.card_topic" CONSTRAINT "card_topic_belongs_to_topic" FOREIGN KEY (topicid) REFERENCES topic(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
    TABLE "print.print_topic" CONSTRAINT "print_topic_belongs_to_topic" FOREIGN KEY (topicid) REFERENCES topic(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
    TABLE "antique.antique_topic" CONSTRAINT "topic_antique_belongs_to_topic" FOREIGN KEY (topicid) REFERENCES topic(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
    TABLE "lp.lp_topic" CONSTRAINT "topic_lp_belongs_to_topic" FOREIGN KEY (topicid) REFERENCES topic(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
    TABLE "stationary.stationary_topic" CONSTRAINT "topic_stationary_belongs_to_topic" FOREIGN KEY (topicid) REFERENCES topic(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
    TABLE "topic" CONSTRAINT "topics_have_parent" FOREIGN KEY (parent_topicid) REFERENCES topic(id) ON DELETE SET NULL
Triggers:
    topic_delete AFTER DELETE ON topic FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE add_into_queue_task()
    topic_update AFTER UPDATE ON topic FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE add_into_queue_task()
    update_topic_updated BEFORE UPDATE ON topic FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_updated_column()
```

`parent_topicid`-field is recursive, pointing to the primary key.

With `npx prisma db pull` Prisma created the corresponding model:

```
  model topic {
    id               Int                @id @default(autoincrement())
    parent_topicid   Int?
    topic            String?            @db.VarChar
    public           Boolean?           @default(true)
    creator          String?            @db.VarChar(12)
    created          DateTime           @default(now()) @db.Timestamptz(6)
    updater          String?            @db.VarChar(12)
    updated          DateTime?          @default(now()) @db.Timestamptz(6)
    antique_topic    antique_topic[]
    book_topic       book_topic[]
    card_topic       card_topic[]
    lp_topic         lp_topic[]
    print_topic      print_topic[]
    topic            topic?             @relation("topicTotopic", fields: [parent_topicid], references: [id], onUpdate: NoAction, map: "topics_have_parent")
    other_topic      topic[]            @relation("topicTotopic")
    stationary_topic stationary_topic[]
  
    @@index([parent_topicid])
    @@schema("public")
  }
```

Now I tried to make initial baseline for migration:

```
$ npx prisma migrate diff --from-empty --to-schema-datamodel prisma/schema.prisma --script > prisma/migrations/0_init/migration.sql
Error: P1012

error: Field "topic" is already defined on model "topic".
  -->  schema.prisma:1340
   |
1339 |   print_topic      print_topic[]
1340 |   topic            topic?             @relation("topicTotopic", fields: [parent_topicid], references: [id], onUpdate: NoAction, map: "topics_have_parent")
   |
```

As you may see, Prisma is not happy with the field it automatically created from my table. From my perspective, the table is set up correctly. What should I do to get a baseline created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that Prisma is encountering a conflict because the name "topic" is being used for both a field and a relation in your model.

Try changing

```
topic            topic?             @relation("topicTotopic", fields: [parent_topicid], references: [id], onUpdate: NoAction, map: "topics_have_parent")
```

to:

```
parentTopic      topic?             @relation("topicTotopic", fields: [parent_topicid], references: [id], onUpdate: NoAction, map: "topics_have_parent")
```

also the autogenerated other_topics sounds odd, perhaps sub_topics is a better name